# How to use the ornamental fonts locally? shall we have a possible list for the future use?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, metafont, ornamental-fonts

we come across the ornamental fonts, in most of the cases, especially  in designing the title pages and chapter titles, parts, sections etc.,

> How to identify the fontfamily name(or how to use the font) locally in our document.

Here is the one way..

`\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.5in}`

To use this, we are going with the very usual way,

`{\titlefont{The text which we want}}`

which satisfy our needs.

Most of our users are poor in searching the font family and how to use that(including me).

In this post, if we can give a MWE which provides ornamental fonts, it may motivate others to use the others fonts also and will give a motivation to create their title pages using latex itself.

Thanks in advance.

I am using Texlive 2013 as backend and texstudio as a front end, and pdflatex.

Comment: If you’re using `pdflatex` and commands like `\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.5in}`, did you really mean to add the `fontspec` tag?  Using ornamental fonts is easy in `xetex` and `luatex`, with `fontspec`; the problem is making the money to buy the fonts!

Comment: In this post, could you give an MWE please?

Comment: `\titlefont`, as you've defined it, does not take an argument. It is a font switch.